# Moved location of deriveddata now getting errors

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, xcode8

I'm using XCode 8. I have a cocoapods based project (therefore using .xcworkspace). I relocated my DerivedData folder to another location then back again. Now I'm seeing the following error in XCode on project launch:

Missing file
/Users/......../DerivedData/project1/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftChart/SwiftChart.framework/Headers/SwiftChart-Swift.h is missing from working copy

There are a couple of these but all refer to the same framework. I have other frameworks which don't appear to be affected.

I have tried:
- deleting my xcworkspace file and recreating (using pods)
- going into 'workspace settings' in XCode and confirming my DerivedData location is default.
- tried a commit and get: 'The working copy "Project 1" failed to commit files......error: pathspec '/..../SwiftChart-Swift.h' did not match any files known to git.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please see my updated description...got an error when trying to commit

Comment: I'm having a problem with the framework mentioned in the errors so I am wanting to get this fixed..